# arrange Month order from January - December. How can I do this?

Tags: sql-server

I convert the date into month using cast option and also use Distinct Keyword. Now I want to arrange Month order from January - December. How can I do this?

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) AS INV_DATE 
FROM AP_INVOICE_HEAD 
ORDER BY INV_DATE ASC
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question that's presented with so little information like this. Could you share some more context, such as the query you're running?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) AS INV_DATE FROM AP_INVOICE_HEAD

Comment: as above without your query it's hard to help. I would suggest looking into ORDER BY though

Comment: Output look like: INV_DATE
April
February
June
March
May
September

Comment: I also try this but not working

Comment: What isn't working? Do you want to mix up entries from different years in the same month? Or did you get confused because you used the same name for the column *and* the month name? BTW, the result of `DATENAME` is a string already, there is no need to cast it to a string

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `DISTINCT` keyword, you must use a column from the select clause to sort the result set by.

The simple solution would be to add the month number to the select clause and then use it in the order by clause:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,t.INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) AS INV_DATE, 
        DATEPART(MONTH, INV_DATE) As INT_Month
FROM AP_INVOICE_HEAD
ORDER BY INT_Month
```

Another option that doesn't involve adding another column to the select list is to replace the `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) As INV_DATE
FROM AP_INVOICE_HEAD t
GROUP BY CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12))
ORDER BY MAX(MONTH(t.INV_DATE))
```

**Note:** In the order by clause, `INV_DATE` refers to the column from the table, not to the alias from the select clause.
Even though the `t.` qualifier is not needed here it does make the query more readable.

Comment: Thanks, Its Working @Zohar

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort based on the month you could use `order by Month(date)`

Comment: But i want distinct values

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by on INV_DATE directly since order by will be executed after the select statement...

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,INV_DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) AS INV_DATE 
FROM AP_INVOICE_HEAD ORDER BY INV_DATE
```